# de Broglie wavelength of electrons and holes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, semiconductor-physics

What is the point of computing the de Broglie wavelength for electrons and holes?
I do not understand what we are supposed to learn from this. Does anyone have any idea?

Exercise:

> Alternatively, the de Broglie wavelength can also be given as the thermal de Broglie wavelength.
> Explain the analogy between the de Broglie wavelength equation and the thermal de Broglie wavelength equation.
> Use the above expression to calculate the de Broglie wavelength specifically for electrons
> and holes in different semiconductor material systems and for different temperatures.
> The parameters given in the following table should be used to calculate them. Note that
> here the effective electron and hole masses enter into the calculation, which are each
> related to the rest mass of the electron $m_0$!

Answer (score 2):

I think this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength, does a great job explaining why you'd need to know the de Broglie wavelength.

From a quick read, the basic reasoning is that depending on the physical distance between the particles, you need to use different statistics to derive what their behavior will be. Perhaps oversimplifying, but knowing the particle's de Broglie wavelength as it relates to this inter-particle distancing lets you know whether you need to use QM or can "get away" with classical thermo. Knowing which set of physical situations (equations) you need to be working should in theory give you better answers when you are trying to create accurate tools/chips. etc.

Comment: I do understand this part of the Broglie wavelength. But why apply it to a hole? is not a hole a quantum system already from the beginning? therefore you know what equation to use.

Comment: I'm no expert on semi-conductor or solid state physics, so I'd say you've probably got a point. At some level this seems like a HW question which isn't motivated all too well, and they just want you to use the 'right equation'. I would think that in general you can do classical physics with 'holes' just as you can with electrons, since they don't represent anything other than an electron missing. So there might be situations where you need to get de Broglie of the 'hole', but I'm not sure WHY, or IF that would be different from the de Broglie of the electron itself.

Answer (score 1):

tau's answer is great, but I wanted to add a slightly different spin on it which is relevant in semiconductors (or really any crystalline material). The de Broglie wavelength is a very rough measure of the "size" of a particle, and this can be rather different for electrons and holes due to band structure (effective mass is a proxy for this). If one creates a crystal which is smaller than this characteristic size, one observes quantum confinement effects - nonzero minimum kinetic energy, discrete spectra, etc. It is often the case that through judicious choice of material, heterostructures, and other nanoscience tricks, you can control the degree of confinement for the electron and hole independently to achieve interesting optical and electrical properties for applications, or examination of fundamental questions in condensed matter.